# Communicate with service using X509Certificate2

Tags: x509certificate

I am attempting to communicate with an outside service using an `X509Certificate2` which is installed locally on my machine. When i attempt to read the request stream i am receiving an error which states that i am not able to communicate with the service. I am wondering if there is anything glaringly wrong with my request or if there is anything else i should take into consideration when making a request like this.
This was previously working in a console app and i am moving this to a web project.

Update: I added proxy settings in my config and that created a different error. "The ServicePointManager does not support proxies with the https scheme"

```
<defaultProxy> 
            <proxy usesystemdefault = "false" proxyaddress="https://theserverIamtryingtoreach:{port}" bypassonlocal="false"/> 
    </defaultProxy>


X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(strMIBPFX, strPwd);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURL);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCertificate);
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
string postData = "";
GetRequestXml(objEntity);
postData = GetXml();
string strFileName = _intCounter + "_" + objEntity.PolicyNumber + ".xml";
SaveXMLOnDisk(postData, _strDailyReq + "/" + strFileName); 
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentType = "application/xml;charset=UTF-8";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
strFileName = _intCounter + "_" + objEntity.Number.Trim() + ".xml";
SaveXMLOnDisk(responseFromServer, _strDailyMibRes + "/" + strFileName);
```

Comment: where is exact error message?

Comment: Because of the type of service i am communicating with i am not able to see the request or get the response code I.E. 400,500 etc. When i get to data stream it throws an exception."Unable to communicate with service"

Comment: where is exact error message?

Comment: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: Try accessing `strURL` through your browser.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution proved to be that the URL i was using was incorrect. I also had to ensure that the certificate was installed correctly on my development environment. After that i was able to send a test post using postman and was able to trouble shoot.